# Jquery tabs are set to display none when click on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs, dropdown

I am working on a project where I have `jquery tabs` and `jquery dropdown`. When I click on jquery dropdown it close my tabs.

Code is below

```
<div class="dropdownjs">
    <input type="text" class="fakeinput" readonly="">
    <ul placement="top-left" style="max-height: 354.167px;">
        <li value="- Day -" selected="selected" class="" tabindex="-1"> - Day - </li>
        <li value="1" tabindex="-1">1</li>
        <li value="2" tabindex="-1">2</li>
        <li value="3" tabindex="-1">3</li>
        <li value="4" tabindex="-1">4</li>
        <li value="5" tabindex="-1">5</li>
        <li value="6" tabindex="-1">6</li>
        <li value="7" tabindex="-1">7</li>
        <li value="8" tabindex="-1" class="selected">8</li>
        <li value="9" tabindex="-1">9</li>
        <li value="10" tabindex="-1">10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and tabs are

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="col-md-2 dashboard-main">
        <li><a class="active" href="#profile-tab-one">General Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile-page-tab-two">second tab </a></li>            
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

jquery is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Please help me how can I fix this issue.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you share jquery code you have written for dropdown.

Comment: <script src="assets/js/material/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>   i have include this js